# Promise exception: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I cannot use `promise` in my application (angular2).
In my service i wrote a function:

```
getItems(status: string) : Promise<Items[]>{
    return new Promise(resolve,reject => {
            this.items = someMethod(status);
             if(this.items!=null){
                 resolve(this.items);
             }
             else{
                 reject("failed to get items");
             }
         });
}
```

and i'm using it from my component:

```
this.service.getItems("someStatus").then(data => this.items = data);
```

but i'm getting an exception:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

what is the problem? how can i fix that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If your arrow function has more than one parameter, they have to be wrapped in parentheses. `(resolve, reject) =>` rather than `resolve, reject =>`.

Comment: At the minute you're effectively calling `new Promise` with two arguments -`resolve` (which is `undefined`) and `reject => { ... }`.

Comment: Are you sure your code is compiling?

Comment: I wrapped parameters in parentheses and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters `resolve` and `reject` must be inside parenthesis

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
});
```